# If returning wrong answer (python)

Tags: python

I am working through the "Learn python the hardway." I apologize if this is a duplicate but I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. When I enter anything less than 50 it tells me to try again, and upon the second time calls a string in another function. If I enter something greater than 50 same thing on the second entry it calls another string in another function. it will call from green_dragon() and print "Both dragons cook you alive and eat you." Thank you for any insight you are able to offer. I apologize for the simplicity, lol. Had to make my own "game and I'm not that creative yet, lol.

```
def gold_room():
    print "You have entered a large room filled with gold."
    print "How many pieces of this gold are you going to try and take?"
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    how_much = int(choice)
    too_much = False
    while True:
        if how_much <= 50 and too_much:
            print "Nice! you're not too greedy!"
            print "Enjoy the gold you lucky S.O.B!"
            exit("Bye!")

        elif how_much > 50 and not too_much:
            print "You greedy MFKR!"
            print "Angered by your greed,"
            print "the dragons roar and scare you into taking less."

        else:
            print "Try again!"
        return how_much

def green_dragon():
    print "You approach the green dragon."
    print "It looks at you warily."
    print "What do you do?"
    wrong_ans = False
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "yell at dragon" and wrong_ans:
            dead("The Green Dragon incinerates you with it's fire breath!")
        elif choice == "approach slowly" and not wrong_ans:
            print "It shows you its chained collar."
        elif choice == "remove collar"and not wrong_ans:
            print "The dragon thanks you by showing you into a new room."
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "Both dragons cook you alive and eat you."
            exit()
```

Comment: You never change `too_much`, so the first `if` will never succeed.

Comment: And in the second function, you never change `wrong_ans`, so the first `if` can never succeed.

Comment: What's the point of these two variables?

Comment: im sorry, change "too_much"? I thought I just had to set it False and the "while True" would keep looping until something less than or equal to 50 was entered

Comment: I'm trying to get it to keep asking for input until the conditions of each if is met.

Comment: The `return` statement exits the function, so it ends the loop.

Comment: It probably shouldn't be indented inside the `while`.

Comment: And `exit()` ends the whole script.

Comment: Im attempting to make my own "text based game" for an exercise in these lessons.

Comment: Tony Tannous' edit fixed it. i see what i was doing wrong. and thank you, i removed the return .

Comment: @Barmar what should not be indented inside the while ?

Comment: @TonyTannous The `return` statement.

Comment: @Barmar true. I did not cocer that.. just helped him with loop. Perhaps I will edit as its an important comment.

Comment: i had put the return there because I kept getting an error saying that i referenced something that was defined yet or something. I forget and had already closed the window where I searched for the fix to that error.

Comment: but i guess i didnt need to define choice as something else, since with the edits it was put in the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
too_much = False

if <= 50 and too_much
```

if `too_much` is set to False, why do you expect the if expression to evaluate to true ? It will never go inside the `if`.

Move user input inside loop as well.

**EDIT:**

To stop your while loop:

```
        too_much = True
        while too_much:
            choice = raw_input("> ")
            how_much = int(choice)
            if how_much <= 50:
                print "Nice! you're not too greedy!"
                print "Enjoy the gold you lucky S.O.B!"
                too_much = False
            else:
                print "You greedy MFKR!"
                print "Angered by your greed,"
                print "the dragons roar and scare you into taking less."
```

Comment: I changed it to True it still does same thing, but now with out the printed out strings.

Comment: I'm trying to make my own text game as part of an exercise in these lessons

Comment: without it it was stopping after one run through. I am trying to have it keep asking for input until it is less than or equal to 50

Comment: @MikeH what should it do if user input is greater than 50 ? ask for input again ? and what should it do its less than 50 ?

Comment: your edit fixed it. yes im wanting it to keep asking to try again until input is less than or equal to 50. i think the fact that i had boolean set wrong and didnt have choice = raw_input("> ") and how_much = int(choice) inside the loop is why it probably kept calling the other funciton.

Comment: @MikeH I edited.  It will keep asking input now until you insert something smaller than 50. I'm glad I've helped you :)

Comment: Thank you, im having a lot of fun learning this. it's very interesting